# Hook into runtime of scripts

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension

I am writing a very simple timer-extension in PHP, and I'm wondering how to:

- Hook into the runtime / get a function of my extension to be called when script execution starts/ends
- Hook into specific functions, e.g., Pdo::query() at start and end.

The purpose is to time given functions or scripts, so that we may easily calculate the execution time etc. I am aware that I can achieve this in pure PHP with:

1. auto_prepend_file / auto_append_file
2. Using an [extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/AOP) that lets me hook into the (beginning of) functions.

But I am mostly interested in C/C++ solutions (in the PHP/Zend API). Perhaps there is even a better way of doing what I want?

Comment: So the PHP wrapping interface is already written (MINIT, RINIT...)? You need the method to hook into the requests processing - isn't RINIT, RSHUTDOWN what you want?

Comment: Well, I guess. Im new to the API, so don't quite know. Since I am timing the scripts, I don't want to start timing too early, and I thought RINIT was called some time before script execution. Thank you for your answer, though! I'll give it a shot. But what about function hooks?

Comment: Any code examples would be nice, even pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that php doesn't have hooks for functions in extensions!
the only hooks you can set in an extension are when the extension is loaded for the first time in apache (MINIT) and everytime a request is recieved by the server (RINIT).

It might somehow be possible to replace a function with your own (i have read somewhere a while ago that you can replace zend engine's functions for parsing,compiling etc).

ps: you might also want to take a look at xdebug, i'm pretty sure that extension does some timing/profiling, you can look how it's done there!